# Turn off nokia here debug messages

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm working with the nokia here api and I noticed a really annoying behavior. I'm making some routing requests with the [`nokia.maps.advrouting.Manager()`](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/enterprise-maps/topics_api_nlp/nokia.maps.advrouting.Manager.html) by calling its [`calculateRoute()`](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/enterprise-maps/topics_api_nlp/nokia.maps.advrouting.Manager.html#topic-apiref__Manager-calculateIsoline-method) method which I pass a callback as argument which should be executed once the response arrives. The thing is that whenever an error occurs inside this callback function (or in any function that get called from within the callback) the here api throws its own error which only references to some code inside here code making it impossible to find the original place where the actual error occurred.

[image: chrome developer console screenshot of a nokia here api error message thrown from within a routing callback function]

Does anybody know if there is a possibility to turn of this behavior and instead get the standard error messages? Or is there a way to find the place where the error occurred anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the Exception from the Coroutines is not possible. The error above looks like you are not using the latest version of the API, where we enhance the error handling. 
The newest Version of the API is 2.5.4.